# What is the recommended dimensions to upload a large background image that would fit to area?

Tags: wordpress, responsive, image-size, responsive-images

I am currently updating a website and the image is with is already at 1920px wide but it is still not a good quality still pixelated a bit.

I have rum it through a small compression already and uploaded to wordpress site but its still not as sharp as it should be.

I would like to know the best and most recommended way to size these images to they come out in the best quality. Especially if they are going to be stretched as a background image.

Comment: Maybe your monitor don't has a good resolution? :D

Comment: No that not it. Im on a Mac and everything is up to standard. I just need to know because we have images that around 4000 pixels wide. And I would like to know what is the best way to upload images without adding to page speed.

Comment: If you are using WordPress, you can checkout this plugin: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/ Thank me later.

Comment: @Mr.Jo we dont use that plugin it made all our images look bad especially the background images were too compressed.

Comment: I'm using it and it looks great at my website raising a lot of money every day ;)

Comment: whats are you settings @Mr.Jo?